# Best C# File Class to parse text file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have following text in my file

```
 Index: D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild
===================================================================
--- D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild   (revision 12414)
+++ D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild   (revision 12416)
--- D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild   (revision 12414)
+++ D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild   (revision 12416)
@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@
  AssemblyFile="$(ToolsBinPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll" />
```

```
-    <FxCop_CriticalErrors>10</FxCop_CriticalErrors>
 +    <FxCop_CriticalErrors>0</FxCop_CriticalErrors>


 <FxCop_Errors>0</FxCop_Errors>
 <FxCop_CriticalWarnings>0</FxCop_CriticalWarnings>
 <FxCop_Warnings>0</FxCop_Warnings>


  Index: D:/QATV2Demo/QATV2Demo/QATConstant.cs
===================================================================
--- D:/QATV2Demo/QATV2Demo/QATConstant.cs   (revision 12414)
+++ D:/QATV2Demo/QATV2Demo/QATConstant.cs   (revision 12416)
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
  {
     public static readonly string PAGE_DATA_DROP_DOWN_MODE = "D";
     public static readonly string PAGE_DATA_GRID_MODE = "G";
-        public static readonly string REPORT = "Report";
+        public static readonly string REPORT = "Report1";
    public static readonly string ITEM_COUNT = "ItemCount";
 }
```

}

Now i have write my own code that gives me result which is the line start with - and +
that shows the content difference of files.

Here is my code

```
 int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string filename = args[0].ToString();


        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("- ")||line.StartsWith("+ "))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line.Trim('-',' ','+'));

                }
                counter++;
            }

            file.Close();
        }
        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

This is ruff code that i have used.

Please tell me which dot net class is best for me in this scenario

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code does what you want, then there's no real need to change the parsing. You can simplify the file reading by using `File.ReadLines`, like this:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("- ") || line.StartsWith("+ "))
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
    ++counter;
}
```

Other than that, you don't say what you want to do with the added and removed lines once you've found them. So I can't give any recommendations there.

Comment: I just want to clarify that is there any other class that might be better in that place. and how can i write this content in XML file (<FxCop_CriticalErrors>10</FxCop_CriticalErrors>)